# Using inner join in sql

Tags: sql

I need to find the assignment marks for course1 for students who also took course2.

1. The "assignment" table, which contains the fields `course`, `assignmentNumber`, and `weight`.
2. The `mark` table, which contains the fields `studentId`, `course`, `assignmentNumber`, and `mark`

I guess I should use inner join in order to group the student numbers of the people who took both courses. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT studentId, sum(0.01*mark*weight)

FROM assignment, mark
WHERE assignment.course = mark.course 
    AND mark.course = 'course1'
    AND assignment.assignmentNumber = mark.assignmentNumber
```

This works well if I want to find course1's final marks, but I just have no idea how to tell the program to consider only the students who took both `course1` and `course2`. Am I missing something? Should I be using a different command altogether? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Inner join can indeed be used, although there are other possibilities too, as is often the case for problems like this. Please give it a try. Even though we can help you with homework, Stack Overflow is not an assignment answer generator.

Comment: Hi, always provide code, even if painfully wrong. It will always help us helping you. Code speaks a lot.  You indeed need to join on courseId and assignment number. Probably a WHERE clause which would requires that student has both course1 and course2. Just a guess

Comment: I understand this post may have come off as a request for you to do my homework, however that was not my intention (and I apologize for that). I have edited my post with the code that I have so far so hopefully that should clear things up a little

Answer (score 0):

you can use in instead of equal. also change

```
and mark.course = 'course1'
```

to

```
and mark.course in ( 'course1', 'course2')
```